# How do you access vector object's member variable and overload it?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, member

I have a struct called `point` and I'm trying to overload the `istream` operator but I cannot access the `x` and `y` variables.

```cpp
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
    point(int x = 0, int y = 0)
            : x{x}, y{y}
        {}
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const std::vector<point> &d){
    return is >> d.x >> d.y;  //error const class std::vector<point> has no member named x or y
}
```

Comment: `d` doesn't have an `x` or `y` member because it isn't a `point`. It's a `std::vector<point>`, which is a container that can contain a number of `point` objects. Your `operator>>` function can't add any new `point` objects to the `vector` or change any `point` objects already in it, either, because the `const` means it promises not to change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
is >> d.x >> d.y
```

does not work since `d` is of type `std::vector<point>`, not `point`. `std::vector<point>` does not have member variables `x` or `y`. `point` does. These are syntactic issues. The more important question is: how do you populate a `std::vector<point>` by reading objects from a file?

I can think of the following options:

1. Don't assume the number of `point` objects to be found in the input stream. Read as many `point` objects as you can and add them to the `std::vector<point>`.
2. Assume that there only a known number of `point` objects -- that could be hard coded or obtained from some other way. In that case, read all of them (assuming they can be read successfully) and add them to the `std::vector<point>`.
3. Read the number of `point` objects from the stream itself. This assumes that number of `point`s that can be read from the stream is also available from the stream. Then, read the expected number of `point` objects (assuming they can be read successfully), and add them to the `std::vector<point>`.

In all these cases, you need the ability to read a `point` from a stream. For that, I suggest,

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, point& p)
{
   return is >> p.x >> p.y;
}
```

To populate a `std::vector<point>` from a stream, you'll have to remove `const` from the second argument. You'll need

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::vector<point>& d)
{
   // Implement the appropriate strategy here to read one point object
   // at a time and add them to d.
   // For the first strategy, you'll need:
   point p;
   while ( is >> p )
   {
       d.push_back(p);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, ideally, you should have the operator overload function as a friend funtion.